# SQL stored procedure variable null checking

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Below is part of a stored procedure that I have, it would be of great help if you can point me why is that even when `@DefaultID` is null after executing the select statement it does not enter the if condition, is there are different method I have to follow to assign the value to `@DefaultID` for it to be available for null checking.

Thank you in advance.

```
DECLARE @DefaultID varchar(25)
DECLARE @ISDefault varchar(1)

SELECT @DefaultID = (SELECT TABLE1.DEFID as DEFID
                     FROM TABLE1
                     WHERE TABLE1.ID = '123')

IF (@DefaultID = '')
    SET @ISDefault = '1'
ELSE
    SET @ISDefault = '0'
```

Comment: Depending on which **database system** you're using, the empty string `''` and `NULL` are **not** equivalent! Checking for `= ''` does **not** check for `NULL` in e.g. SQL Server ...

Comment: comparing (=,<>,<,>,<=,>=) NULL with anything always return special value UNKNOWN, which is always false. You should use IS NULL as told in some answers below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
IF @DefaultID IS NULL
```

Instead of `IF @DefaultID =''`

`NULL` and `''` are two different things.

Answer (score 4):

simply use this :-

```
  IF(@DefaultID is NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check using

`IF ISNULL(@DefaultID, '') = ''` instead of `IF(@DefaultID = '')`

I guess you are using MS Sql server.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(len(@DefaultID) > 0)
 SET @ISDefault = '1'
ELSE
    SET @ISDefault = '0'
```